# Is it possible to host a Wordpress blog with Dropbox?

Tags: wordpress

I'm planning to host a site on Dropbox via *site44.com*. Is it possible for me to a host a Wordpress blog with Dropbox? Thanks.

Comment: Unlikely - dropbox hosts static content, wordpress needs php and mysql.

Comment: Lighten up people. It's not a crime not to know how web sites work.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch:  Of course it isn’t *in general*.  But when you are setting one up then you *have* to know what you are doing.  There’s a reason you need a driving licence before you are allowed to drive a car—running a web site is not that much different.

Comment: you need a license to run a website?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. Site44 provides no ability to execute server-side scripts. Wordpress needs a server that can run the PHP scripting language.

The crucial concept here is that Site44 only supports [static web pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_web_page). Wordpress generates its pages [dynamically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page).